# Completely spammed by a Spam url

Tags: seo, spamming

My website is currently completely spammed by a spam domain with adult content. All those links are showing in traffic for my website and I also see my website ranking getting decreased day by day. I am not sure how to block that website and clear the damage caused by that spam domain.

Any webmaster here here who has ever experienced something of that sort ?
I hope you can give me some advice if ever got out of this situation with least harm.

Comment: *My website is currently completely spammed by a spam domain with adult content. All those links are showing in traffic for my website ...* Can you clarify this? Is a site linking to yours? Or is it something else? What does *showing in traffic* mean? How are you experiencing this? Can you explain more? Otherwise, this seems a bit unclear and contains little actionable information. Cheers!!

Comment: Hi closetnoc, I can see my website rank dropping to page 7 from page 2 after I saw traffic from a adult spam site. What they have done is, add footer link to my website and they have added thousands of spam content pages.

Comment: Thanks for making it clearer. While it can be dangerous to disavow links too redily, this may be one case where even I would suggest it. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you :) Is there any other way to know other spam links that may cause ranking drop ?

Comment: While there are sites that show links to your site, only Google Search Console should be relied upon. Why? Because the others are so slow and do not show you everything. Most of the time links are not an issue. However, this sounds like such a severe offense I would look through my past to see who I p1$$ed off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to make sure that you have registered each version of your website (www vs. non-www) with Google Webmaster Central. From there, this is where you can disavow all of the links from the domains that are doing this as soon as you can. Once you disavow them, Google will not penalize you for being linked to by sites with shady content.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en

You will need to upload a .txt file of all the URLs with links that you want to disavow. To disavow an entire domain simply use:

domain:example.com

Comment: Thank you, I have just added that link for disavow :) Also is there any way I can know other spam links to my site ?

Comment: You can see which links to your site Google has discovered at https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/external-links-domain - Click download latest links to keep up with new links and domains that are doing this to you. That's the best way that I know of. There are also backlink checkers but I assume that Google reports all of the links that it discovers at that link.

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for this link but certainly it is very difficult to find the links that are spammy from this big list.